# Does VSCode has a console like the Sublime Text console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext

On the Sublime Text console we can run python commands, use the Sublime Text api. See the error messages from the packages, and much more. Does VSCode has such feature?

[image: Sublime Text Console]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it has Integrated Terminal and you can chose what to use in it - PowerShell/Bash/CMD, also Debug Console, code Output and Problems tab for the current workspace

[image]